# How to setup proxy authentication in the Debian shell?

Tags: debian, authentication, proxy, http-proxy

I think that once I used

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@address:port/
```

successfully. But now when I use `wget` it shows

> Error parsing proxy URL http://user:passwordaddress:port/: Bad port number.

Why it ignores the <kbd>@</kbd> symbol? How to make it work?

I also tried

```
wget --proxy-user=USERNAME --proxy-password=PASSWORD
```

But it returned

> Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
>   2011-06-09 14:01:18 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: Does the user or password contain a # or / character by any chance? In which case you may need to URI-encode it (`%23`, `%2F`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the following syntax ?

```
   http_proxy=http://address:port/ wget --proxy-user=USERNAME --proxy-password=PASSWORD http://url
```